# How can I unlock an iPhone 3G that no longer has a service plan?

Tags: iphone, unlock

I have an old iPhone 3G which I purchased in Canada and it was locked for three years to Rogers, a service provider.

Last month, I stopped the service and moved to the US. I was not able to use the iPhone because it was still bundled with a Canadian service provider and could not even go into the operating system.

I called the service provider but they won't help me unlock because I've stopped the service.

What can I do now?

Comment: Ha! As if Rogers would unlock it even if you *did* still have service with them.

Answer (score 1):

The programmer chpwn has created a web site where you can see if you can unlock your iPhone at http://caniunlock.com. Look there, and also at http://jailbrea.kr for jailbreak information. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves me correctly you should have installed the firmware 4.2.1 on 3G!
To unlock the phone and the only way 'to make the Jailbreack!